# How to remap arbitrary keys in Centos 7

Tags: keyboard, centos

## I need the following custom layout (because of Vim or Bash):

Esc
Esc ---> Tab
Tab ---> Caps Lock

[desired keyboard layout as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JljdH.png)

I have spent a lot of time to do it permanently, but without success.

## The following attempts do NOT work for Centos 7:

Solution for old good Centos 6:

```
$ cat ~/.Xmodmap  
remove Lock = Caps_Lock  
keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab  
keycode  23 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
```

Works temporarily but not permanently (Centos 7):

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
...  
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock"  
xmodmap -e "keycode  23 = Escape NoSymbol Escape"  
xmodmap -e "keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab"  
...
```

There is no option to achieve desired remapping with the following command:

```
$ mate-keyboard-properties
```

Layouts ---> Options... ---> Caps Lock key behaviour

~/.config/dconf/user  <--- I tried edit a configuration database file

```
 $ dconf-editor
```

a database path: /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/keyboard/kbd/options
does not offer usable option (only needless: caps:none, caps:escape, ...)

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found a solution for CentOS 7 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc). The answer is the one with the using of `dconf-editor`.